# The number of attributes in key schema must match the number of attributes defined in attribute definitions in AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

While creating table in dynamoDB from Node Js. I got the above error.

```
const schema = {
    TableName: "alarms",
    KeySchema: [
        { AttributeName: "alarm_code", KeyType: "HASH" },  //Partition key
        { AttributeName: "controller", KeyType: "RANGE" }  //Sort key
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [
        { AttributeName: "alarm_code", AttributeType: "N" },
        { AttributeName: "controller", AttributeType: "S" },
        { AttributeName: "controller_type", AttributeType: "S" }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {
        ReadCapacityUnits: 10,
        WriteCapacityUnits: 10
    }
}
```

`{ AttributeName: "controller_type", AttributeType: "S" }`

adding this attribute to `AttributeDefinitions` I'm getting this above error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DynamoDB is schemaless, you need only provide attributes which are needed as partition/sort key at the time of creation, this is why the parameter is named [`KeySchema`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTable.html#DDB-CreateTable-request-KeySchema) as its only related to the keys:

> Array Members: Minimum number of 1 item. Maximum number of 2 items.

```
const schema = {
    TableName: "alarms",
    KeySchema: [
        { AttributeName: "alarm_code", KeyType: "HASH" },  //Partition key
        { AttributeName: "controller", KeyType: "RANGE" }  //Sort key
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [
        { AttributeName: "alarm_code", AttributeType: "N" },
        { AttributeName: "controller", AttributeType: "S" }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {
        ReadCapacityUnits: 10,
        WriteCapacityUnits: 10
    }
}
```